# Equally spaced bibliography keys using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm working at a bibliography with `biblatex`. I have to format my cite keys to match some requirements. My current problem is that I found no option to change the horizontal spacing/alignment of the keys. That's my current setup:

[image: citations and keys]

I want it to have the keys spaced equally so that the brackets align like this (but only in the bibliography itself):

```
Text with citation [CD] and this [OBB]

Bibliography:
[  CD ] Some text
[ OBB ] Some text
```

The important aspect here is the alignment of the brackets. How can this be done? And further, is there a way to center the keys within the brackets?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxbibnames=1,maxcitenames=1,defernumbers,%
    doi=false,isbn=false,clearlang=false,backref=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@ONLINE{text:source,
    author={B. Obby},
    title={Sources today},
    url={http://www.example.com},
    urldate={2017-02-20},}
@ONLINE{text:src,
    author={Cicero, Marcus Tullius and Doe, John},
    title={Sources tomorrow},
    url={http://www.example.com},
    urldate={2017-02-20},}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Text with citation and no extended spacing: \autocite{text:src}\\
Text witch citation and ordinary spacing: \autocite{text:source}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxbibnames=1,maxcitenames=1,defernumbers,%
    doi=false,isbn=false,clearlang=false,backref=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\textsc{#1}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\nocite{*}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\hfill#1\hfill}}

\begin{document}

Text with citation and no extended spacing: \autocite{doody}\\
Text witch citation and ordinary spacing: \autocite{herrmann}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]